# node.js azure operations ? definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I am looking at code in node with azure

```
   .where('Key eq ?', key1)
```

I would like to know what is " ?" means .. I do know eq is equal

Comment: It's placeholder where `key1` will be inserted.. so if `key1` is `"hello"` then it will be `"Key eq 'hello'"`

Comment: Esailija Can you add this as an answer and @The Learner mark it as answered. Tx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ? is a placeholder for the parameters passed next. `key1` in this case.